# Responsive grid jQuery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using [this](http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/Zkk0O) snippet for creating mansory-like responsive grid, but when I check elements class, I see class is updated repeatedly. This prevents me from doing additional manipulations on the elements and maybe cause a lot of performance usage. Is there a way for reediting the plugin or is there a better mansory-like plugin for this specific need? As far I researched, this look like the simpliest solution.

Comment: [masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/) is about as "masonry-like" as you get. Why not use it?

Comment: Because this was easier, smaller amount of code and no need to reload another library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Masonry plugins keep access the dom and write into their elements to work, but it looks like this plugin keep writing the class of their elements even if the window is not resized. Try this masonry instead: http://masonry.desandro.com/
If you add a class into one masonry element, the class is preserved. Maybe this suit better your need (and it looks like a little less invasive). It is also jquery-free.

Comment: I managed to make my grid with Masonry. Just to mention that there is also another jQuery plugin which is able to get the desired effect - Wookmark.